# Bind dynamic text from ViewModel with Resource strings in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, text, resources, static, bind

I have the following problem

xaml code:

TextBlock Text="{Binding DynamicText"}

ViewModel

DynamicText = "test";
DynamicText = "test2";
...

I would like this to be multilingual;
For static texts, I use this:

TextBlock Text={Binding MyStrings.StaticString1, Source={StaticResource MyStringWrapper}}

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can build a proxy to get the proper text if this is the only test field you are going to use.
If there are loads of data fields you want to display, I believe the language filter should be in data access layer or data repository.
For static text see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(v=vs.95).aspx